# How to query a SharePoint list and get specfic row based on an ID and display it on a page?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

First, I'm a SharePoint development noob. I'm a web developer and experienced with LAMP, LEMP, Linux, etc. But I got this task I need to do.

**I need to extract a single row from a SharePoint list based on the ID and display this data nicely on a page however I want.**

I have read about the SPQuery class but I don't know how to implement on a new SharePoint 2013 page?

Can you guide me on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `SPQuery` if you want to get specific row based on ID you can simple use `GetItemById`

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList list = web.Lists["Your LIst Name"];
SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(id);
if(item != null)
    {
       string columnvalue = Convert.ToString(item["Columnname"]);
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. Can I implement this code using SharePoint designer? If yes, where should it be placed in the .aspx page?

Comment: no you need to create custom webpart using Visual studio and then after deploy you can add this webpart in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Before you begin to code, I would recommend you to use Webparts with Filters. I do not know, how you would like to specify the ID, but you could let the user decide with a filter webpart.

Maybe this article might help you understand webparts better: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/When-to-use-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-or-the-Content-Search-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-346a0f48-38de-409b-8a58-3bdca1768929?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

One popular filter is explained in this video: [The choice filter Webpart](https://youtu.be/QX1canjoM0w)